# Attic “floor” insulation

Tags: insulation, attic, humidity, winter, canada

I have a cabin soon to be my house. Recently added on to it.
I reinsulated the attic of the original house and insulated the addition. Both should be insulated to r40-r60.
We turn the heat down during the week to 12-15 c. And up to 20-22 on the weekend
Concern
Outside temp currently -8 64% humidity, original attic-9 84%, new addition-14c 79%. Inside temp is 29 c humidity 30-50%.  We heat with wood stove and forced air propane.

We live at a lake beach front it it matters
I feel the original house attic needs more ventilation
How can it be colder in the attic than outside?
Why is it more humid in the attic?
In case it matters it was -20 c last night now -8

Comment: Do you have proper ventilation in the attic?  Outside air comes in at the bottom of the roof and out the top.  Humidly depends on the temperature.

Comment: Attic temps should be slow to change unless you have a nice bright sun hitting the roof.  Hours of -20 and a cloudy sky, the attic air does not change fast enough to match outside with passive(just vents) ventilation.

Comment: Ventilatoon in original house needs a little work but addition is done. 
Today outside is -8 61%h, original attic -12 77% h, new attic -13 75% h. So closer to outside. Again last night was -16. 
So maybe it was just the temperature swing. I am hoping it is not the inside heat adjustment from 10 to 20. 

I will continue to monitor.

Comment: Great comment that the attic air temp and humidity will not adjust to outside that quickly

Comment: Insulation is to keep the living space warm/not lose heat as fast, The attic is basically left to itself to get cold or hot.  Attic ventilation is to keep humidly down to outside levels and to help cool the roof deck/attic a bit when the sun beats down on the roof.  Imagine you have had cloudy days lately, get some sun on the roof and it will be t-shirt temps up there.

Comment: I understand the heat idea but I am surprised the humidity is high then outside